# What is the good db property, for an keys's array for python with App Engine?

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

For the moments bars represents a String with all the Bar ids with ';' separator

like `6;5;9;15`

```
class Foo(db.Model):
    id = db.StringProperty(multiline=True)
    name = db.StringProperty(multiline=True)   
    bars = db.TextProperty()

class Bar(db.Model):
    id = db.StringProperty(multiline=True)
    name = db.StringProperty(multiline=True)
```

What must I do to explicit Foo contains some bars in db?
And also how is going to look my :

```
f = Foo()
f.name= 'aName'
f.id = '3615'
f.bars = '6;5;9;15'
f.put()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a start, you never want to store multiple values inside a single textfield. AppEngine's datastore supports multi-valued properties (such as `ListProperty`): you should use those.

That said, there's no multi-valued equivalent of `ReferenceProperty` built in. [This article](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/modeling.html) on the AppEngine documentation site gives a good example of how to model a list of keys.

Comment: "you never want to store multiple values inside a single textfield" I know it's why I put my question

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is a many-to-many relationship, you can use `db.ListProperty(db.Key)` for a list of the `Bar`s' Keys, or, if you really want to just store the integer IDs, `db.ListProperty(int)`.

If each `Bar` can only be a bar of a single foo, it's probably better to use a `ReferenceProperty` in the `Bar` entity, then use the automatic backreference in `Foo` to get a query for all of the bars.

By the way, naming a property "id" and making it a multiline string is probably a Bad Idea.