# Retrieve values of an entity by the Django's template with db.ListProperty(db.Key)

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

Thanks to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8185255/what-is-the-good-db-property-for-an-keyss-array-for-python-with-app-engine/8185488#8185488) I changed my class to:

```
class Foo(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty(multiline=True)   
    bars = db.ListProperty(db.Key)

class Bar(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty(multiline=True)
```

Here a piece of my Django Template

```
   <div >
     <h3>{{ current_foo.name }}</h3>
      {% for bar in current_foo.bars %}
         <a href="/dialog_bar.html?id={{ bar.id }}"  >{{ bar.name }}</a>
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

I don't manage to get the bars's name and the bars's id, How Can I do that?
What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best bet is to define a simple method or property on your Foo model that queries the database for the relevant Bars.

```
class Foo(db.Model):
    ...
    def get_bars(self):
        return db.get(self.bars)
```

Then you can call this in the template:

```
{% for bar in current_foo.get_bars %}
```

Comment: isn't it a problem to request the db foreach bar?

Comment: @ChristopheDebove: It very well might be a problem, but without storing a StringListProperty containing all of the names along with the list of IDs, there's no way to avoid fetching them from the database if you want to display them.